# Route issue on browser back with internet explorer and windows edge browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, routes, seo, windows-10

This is my RouteConfig and I used an SEO friendly url on my site. The browser "back" button works fine in Chrome and Firefox but there is an issue in Internet Explorer and Windows Edge.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
            "SearchType", // Route name
            "Search/{SpaceType}/{Type}/{Location}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "SearchListSpace", action = "SearchListSpace", Location = UrlParameter.Optional }  // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "View", // Route name
            "{SpaceType}/{City}/{List_Space_Code}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "ListSpace", action = "View" } // Parameter defaults
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
}
```

[I get this, when the back button is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAtXH.png)

Any ideas on how to solve this problem would be appreciated.